# How to pass a file as command line argument in Netbeans

Tags: file, netbeans, command-line-arguments

I have trying to work out with Netbeans for the last two days.
I am writing a scanner program that takes input of the scanner from a file token_list.java.
So How can we give this token_list.java as an argument to the Main file ( Scanner.java).
When I am doing it on the Unix system using command line argument all works fine and well. The problem comes when i am doing it on netbeans.
I have even tried giving the file name token_list.java as an argument in the run properties in the project. But then later i realized that the command line arguments for the run properties are for just giving the inputs rather than the file name.

Update : The command that I give in unix is 
             $java Scanner input.text
So What I am now trying to do in netbeans is right click on the scanner.java and run it.
But it then gives the error that no arguments have been passed. I am taking the file name in argv

Comment: What do you mean by "inputs rather than the file name"? Can you maybe edit your answer and add the command that works in Unix that you are trying to replicate in NetBeans, then it will be easier to understand the problem.

Comment: PS Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)

Answer (score 5):

There is a community contributed plugin named NbRunWithArgs https://github.com/tusharvjoshi/nbrunwithargs which will provide you "Run with Arguments" option when you run Java project or a single Java file.

You may want to use this plugin, more details are available [on blog post here.](http://netbeanside61.blogspot.in/2014/03/command-line-arguments-for-java.html)

UPDATE (24 mar 2014) This plugin is now available in NetBeans Plugin Portal that means it can be installed from Plugins dialog box from the available plugins shown from community contributed plugins, in NetBeans IDE 8.0

[image: Run with Arguments plugin as shown in NetBeans IDE 8.0 plugins dialog box]

Answer (score 3):

In Netbeans, right-click on your Project name and click Properties
In the "Run", you can define, which class is the main-class, the working directory and arguments
After that, try to run the **project**, not the class itself !

Comment: It worked for me with the python plugin. I thought these properties were only for java.